# How to set form via jQuery after AJAX response

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to change my Spring form for a new one after an AJAX call to my Controller that gives me the object that I want to map to the form.

The Form declaration:

```
<form method="POST" action="/addInput" id="registerForm" >
```

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url : '${findNewFormz}',
  type : 'GET',
  data: {'data': id},
  success : function(data) {
    $('#registerForm').html(data);
  },
  fail: function () {
    console.log("Encountered an error")
  }
});
```

Here is the point: $('#registerForm').html(data);
It doesn't work like expected, sets the view all in blank. Is there any command or method to update the form and all the values from it?

My Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/formIDz")
public @ResponseBody HistoricBO getNewFormz(String data, @ModelAttribute("historic") HistoricBO historic) {
    return historic;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the data that is returned from the call please ? Is it HTML ?

Comment: your api response is in json format it cant directly mapped in your form data

Comment: if your form is consist any table and your api response is also json array then you can create that table dynamically and put that in form data